# How to extract age from a string?

Tags: javascript, string, text-extraction

Here is my string
`const data = "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp90zt, age=47"`

I want the output as `[58, 64];`

what i tried,

```js
    const filtered = data.replace(/\D+/g, ' ').trim().split(' ').map(e => parseInt(e));
    console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: In your example output, should it be `[58, 64, 47]`? Or do you want the last age in the string omitted for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp90zt, age=47";
// Split by \s
data = (data.split(/,\s+/));
// Result array
const res = [];
// Loop array
for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const el = data[i].split(/\=/);
  if(el[0] === "key") res.push({ key: el[1] });
  if(el[0] === "age") res.push({ age: el[1] });
}
 
 console.log(res);
```

Or if you need just digits, use this code. It takes your string, then makes a global replacement with a template (the `replace` method with the specified `RegEx`), where it captures the parts as `age=number`, then each of these captured parts is split with the `=` symbol (the `split` method) and returns only a `number` after the equal sign.

```js
let data = "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp90zt, age=47";

// Parse
const matched = data.replace(/(?:key=.*?)age=(\d+)/g, (m) => m.split(/\=/)[2]);

// Log
console.log(matched);
```

Comment: Upvoted. I like your second example but can you explain what does it do?

Comment: It takes your string, then makes a global replacement with a template (the `replace` method with the specified `RegEx`), where it captures the parts as `age=number`, then each of these captured parts is split with the `=` symbol (the `split` method) and returns only a number after the equal sign.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. May you update it in the answer section so others can see it.

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to do that. instead you want to split by ',' first to get your pairs:

```
var pairs = data.split(',');
```

then loop through your pairs and get your name/value pairs

```
var c = pair.split('=');
var name = c[0].trim();
var value = c[1].trim();
```

something like that should work. here's full code:

```
var results = [];
var pairs = data.split(',');
pairs.forEach(pair => {
  var c = pair.split('=');
  var name = c[0].trim();
  var value = c[1].trim();
  if(name == 'age')
    results.push(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, I would like to answer. 
Something like this should solve your case!

```
var data = "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp90zt, age=47";
var ages = [];
data.split(', ').forEach(e => {
    var item = e.split('=');
    if(item[0] === 'age'){
        return ages.push(parseInt(item[1]));
    }
});
console.log(ages);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const filtered = data.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)
```

You use a regular expression (/\d+/g) to match what you are looking for, i.e. numbers in a string. This worked for me in the past when trying to get numbers from a string as an array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp90zt, age=47" , result = [];

data = data.split(',');
data.forEach(item => {
  if(item.indexOf('age=') !== -1)
  {
    result.push(parseInt(item.trim().split("age=")[1]));
  }
})


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will extract exactly what you want:

```js
let data = "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp90zt, age=47";
let matches = (data.match(/age=([0-9]*?),/g)).map(m => parseInt(m.replace(/age=|,/g, '')))

console.log(matches)
```

The first part of this solution is:

```
data.match(/age=([0-9]*?),/g)
```

This part matches the following: age=(numbers),
If we have `key=IAfpK, age=58,` the full match will be: age=58,
Thats the reason of the second part:

```
.map(m => parseInt(m.replace(/age=|,/g, '')))
```

Here we translate the matches (`['age=58,', 'age=64,']`) to get just what we want, the elements between "age=" and ",".

The output, an array of ages: [58, 64];

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the data might be more useful than just extracting just what you need. I'm not sure why `47` is not included in the expected result so in the example below I've added a `.filter(age => age > 50)`, but you can change this to whatever you prefer.

```js
const data = "key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp90zt, age=47";
const pairs = data.split(", ").map(pair => pair.split("=", 2));

const items = [];
for (const [key, value] of pairs) {
  const item = items[items.length - 1];
  if (!item || key in item) {
    items.push({ [key]: value });
  } else {
    item[key] = value;
  }
}

for (const item of items) {
  item.age = parseInt(item.age, 10);
}

console.log(items);
console.log(items.map(item => item.age).filter(age => age > 50));
```